# Send / receive data from js / jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, send, jplayer

I have a problem, I'm building my own player on website. And I have some data (2 variables) from js/jQuery and I want to send it anywhere I click (other pages of my site). I thought that the cookies are good idea but its not, sending by post - I don't know how.

Please give some tips.

```
var cookieValue = $.cookie("czasplajera", { path: '/' });
$("#info").html(cookieValue);

$("#jquery_jplayer_1").jPlayer("play",parseInt(cookieValue));
$("#jquery_jplayer_1").bind($.jPlayer.event.timeupdate, function(event) {
     var czasplajera = Math.floor(event.jPlayer.status.currentTime);
     //$('#info').html(czasplajera);
     $.cookie("czasplajera",czasplajera, { expires: 1, path: '/' });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

When you are reading a cookie value, you only supply one argument, the key:

```
var cookieValue = $.cookie("czasplajera");
```

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/K5AgD/

When you pass more than one argument, the cookie library things you are trying to set a cookie value:

```
var cookieValue = $.cookie("czasplajera", "whateverValue", { path: '/' });
```

---

When you do this (which is what your code is doing):

```
var cookieValue = $.cookie("czasplajera", { path: '/' });
```

the jQuery plugin is probably trying to set a cookie value and isn't returning anything useful so your first line of code above is not reading the cookie value.

---

Also, since the cookie functionality is not built into jQuery (it's a separate plug-in), you have to make sure you have the code loaded for the cookie plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the cookie is set:

```
$.cookie("CookieName", "Cookie Value");
```

Then you can retrieve data inside with:

```
$.cookie("CookieName");
```